# AIX Shell Prepend code being run to an output logfile along with stdout data

Tags: loops, shell, unix, scripting, tee

How do I prepend the code I ran, either directly at the  `shell prompt` or via `shell-script` to an output logfile I created.

```
#something like this 
echo ' Until < code > do ; <code> done; case       <code> esac ; ' >> op.log ;
Until < code > do ; <code> done; case       <code> esac ; | tee -a op.log
```

Instead of crafting an `echo`  statement I'd like to know if its poss through  a 'cody' approach to capture whatever you just ran and stick that in your log file, ( at the beginning ) so when I open that log - I 'll know what code produced this . It should be a one time prepend as against repeating with every loop iteration.

Comment: You want to log your own activity? You can use program `script` together with shell option `-v`

Comment: well kind of but not quite. I want  that `'log' `on top of my `stdout log`  as against 1 log with all my  `history`. . So anyone other than me can see  what command produced this result, when a logfile is opened  &   I wanna try something that can work on  any 101 `Linux` including `adb`